# Typescript ensure correct class type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to strongly type my ID attributes in my classes, but look like typescript doesn't care.

```
static create(id: CustomerWalletID | ProviderWalletID, name: string, owner: CustomerID) {
    return new CustomerWallet(id, {
      name,
      owner,
    });
  }

  private constructor(id: CustomerWalletID, private props: Args) {
    super(id);
  }
```

As you can see the constructor expects `CustomerWalletID` and can receive `CustomerWalletID | ProviderWalletID` as args, which is supposed to trigger a compilation warning. It doesn't.

Here are my ID classes :

```
export class CustomerWalletID extends ValueObject<string> {
  equals(customerWalletID: CustomerWalletID) {
    return customerWalletID.value === this.value;
  }
}

export class ProviderWalletID extends ValueObject<string> {
  equals(providerWalletID: ProviderWalletID) {
    return providerWalletID.value === this.value;
  }
}

export abstract class ValueObject<T> {
  protected readonly _value: T;

  constructor(props: T) {
    this._value = Object.freeze(props);
  }

  get value(): T {
    return this._value;
  }

  public abstract equals(_vo: ValueObject<T>): boolean;
}
```

What am I doing wrongly?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that does not work in TypeScript the way it works in other (C#, Java, ...) languages. TypeScript uses "structural" typing, meaning it will consider 2 classes to be the same (or compatible) if they have the same properties. As a result of that, if you want to achieve strong typing for the IDs, you need to add an extra property with unique name in each of those ID classes (not pretty, I know).

```
interface CustomerWalletId {
  customerWalletId: string; // not just "Id"
}

interface ProviderWalletId {
  providerWalletId: string; // not just "Id"
}
```

Comment: I'll try, as long as it does the job, it's fine :D Thank you Zdravko

Comment: Now it yields for unused vars, I fixed it with some `@ts-ignore`, but in case someone has a better idea that is sure to not be removed by any linting tools, that could be great.

Comment: you can declare a getId() function that returns the id property that you declared and use that as an accessor